# How do I fix the 'Element implicitly has an 'any' type' error when using Prisma with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, prisma

I wanted function to fetch data from my db with prisma and typescript so i did this simple function

```
export async function getAll(model : string) {     
    const results = await prisma[`${model}`].findMany()     
    await  prisma.$disconnect()     
    return results }
```

it works fine but I have typescript errors

`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'PrismaClient<PrismaClientOptions, never, RejectOnNotFound | RejectPerOperation | undefined>'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'PrismaClient<PrismaClientOptions, never, RejectOnNotFound | RejectPerOperation | undefined>`

I'm a newbie with typescript and prisma and i have no idea how to solve this error

Answer (score 0):

haven't used prisma but I understand that out of the box it should work with typescript making a simple query like `await prisma.<model>.<query>...`.

So if you want wrap the prisma methods in your own function, you must make sure that you preserve the types. You mention you are new to prisma and typescript together but I don't individually how well you know them so I will try and explain in an easy to understand way so that it's actually useful.

In this case, you are typing the prisma model name as string (your `model` argument for `getAll` function). This means that as far as typescript is concerned any call to prisma's functions are looking for a model that is of type `string`, but because prisma has generated the model types for you the type `string` does not satisfy a lookup into the models because you do not have a model for every single string, that's an infinite number of models. In other words there is no exactness, it would be like in plain js looking for something in a map or object but all you know is that it is a string.

So your goal should be to wrap the method in a way where the types are exact. Using generics you can ensure that whatever is typed as model name has its exact type preserved, in this case these are string literals representing the names of the models. Here is an example

```
const createString = <T extends string>(str:T)=>str;
```

If I were to use this as follows

```
const str = createString('hi');
```

The type of `str` is `hi`.

For your example, this becomes

```
export async function getAll <T extends string>(model: T) {
  const results = await prisma[`${model}`].findMany();
  await prisma.$disconnect();
  return results;
}
```

This ensures that argument model is passed down to `prisma[model]` as typed, so if you type a correct model name it should work. If you further want to constrain the argument so that it itself only accepts valid string literals you could do the following

```
type MyPrisma = typeof prisma
export async function getAll <T extends keyof MyPrisma>(model: T) {
  const results = await prisma[`${model}`].findMany();
  await prisma.$disconnect();
  return results;
}
```

This ensures that any argument passed to `getAll` is a valid model name string literal, may not be necessary but whatever.

Alternatively you can just query using prisma directly.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

model type should be like this. if you have `User` model, if you write `prisma.user` you would have this type for `.user`

```
Prisma.UserDelegate<Prisma.RejectOnNotFound | Prisma.RejectPerOperation | undefined>
```

depends on how many model types you have

you could write a custom type

```
type PrismaModel=
    Prisma.UserDelegate<Prisma.RejectOnNotFound | Prisma.RejectPerOperation | undefined> |
    Prisma.AnotherModelDelegate<Prisma.RejectOnNotFound | Prisma.RejectPerOperation | undefined> | ..soon
```

instead of `model:String` you could pass

```
model:PrismaModel
```